# Is there a BDD framework for testing Javascript that uses Gherkin DSL?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cucumber, bdd, javascript-framework

I am very much a fan of BDD and [Behat](http://behat.org/) for PHP.  Is there something equivalent for Javascript, ie, that uses the [Gherkin DSL](http://docs.behat.org/en/gherkin/index.html)?  Everything I've seen so far is more in line with RSpec, and I would like to approach JS testing more like Cucumber, if possible

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer a valid and the Kyuri repo is out of date. The correct answer is Johnno Nolan's: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js

Comment: @Xolv.io You're right. Updated. Thx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is one being developed as i write - help out if you can http://groups.google.com/group/cukes/browse_thread/thread/56ba76eac2e9dab3

Edit and now its here!

[The official Cucumber for javascript](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js)

Answer (score 6):

[cucumber.js](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) should be exactly what you're looking for. Not quite finished, but might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 4):

[Yadda](http://github.com/acuminous/yadda) supports a Given / When / Then style syntax. It plugs into other testing frameworks like qunit, mocha or casperjs, and allows you to write tests as follows...

```
Scenario: A bottle falls from the wall

    Given 100 green bottles are standing on the wall
    when 1 green bottle accidentally falls
    then there are 99 green bottles standing on the wall

Scenario: No bottles are left

    Given 1 green bottles are standing on the wall
    when 1 green bottle accidentally falls
    then there are 0 green bottles standing on the wall
```

Answer (score 2):

Kyuri: https://github.com/nodejitsu/kyuri